# FileAlreadyExistsException for a deleted directory

Tags: java-8, java.nio.file

For the purpose of making a backup, I copy a directory with tests scripts to another location. For this I'm using Files.walkFileTree(fromDir, SimpleFileVisitor).

This works as expected and I can copy it multiple times without any problems.

But when I delete the target directory via Windows File explorer I get a java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException on the target directory when I try to make a back up.

I'm pretty sure that the target directory is not there.

When I close the Java program and start it again, it works again. It is as if manually deleting the directory locks the 'non-existing' target directory and Java throws a FileAlreadyExistsException.

Here are the relevant parts of the SimpleFileVisitor

I'm using these options when copying the files

```
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS
```

```
  @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
    {
      Path copyDir = toDir.resolve(fromDir.relativize(dir));
      try {
        Files.createDirectories(copyDir);
      }
      catch(IOException ioe) {
        LOG.error("Failed to create directory " + copyDir.toString());
        throw ioe;
      }
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
    {
      Path toFile = toDir.resolve(fromDir.relativize(file));
      try {
        Files.copy(file, toFile, opts);
      }
      catch(IOException ioe) {
        LOG.error("Failed to create file " + toFile.toString());
        throw ioe;        
      }
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
```

I was expecting that deleting the target directory via Windows File Explorer would not cause this problem, but apparently it does.

Is there anything I could do to make the copy action possible in case someone deletes the directory via Windows File Explorer.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but there may be some process keeping an open handle somewhere which keeps it from being "truly" deleted. I'd assume it's the Java process since restarting it makes everything work, but I can't be positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think so. The deletion takes place outside the Java program. The Java program only copies files from the source to target directory.

Comment: You might be able to check by running the resource monitor.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will look into it (I'm not really familiar with resmon).